# Why does django think these values are different?

Tags: django, django-templates

In my template, I am creating a select control from the list in **qualifications**. I have added the comment line to try to figure out why I could not designate a given row as **selected**.

```
{% for qual in qualifications %}
    <!-- form.qualid.value ({{ form.qualid.value }}) {% if form.qualid.value == qual.empqualid %}equals{% else %}does not equal{% endif %} qual.empqualid ({{ qual.empqualid }}) -->
    <option value="{{ qual.empqualid }}"{% if qual.empqualid == form.qualid.value %} selected{% endif %}>{{ qual.EmpQualName }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

A sample of my results:

```
<!-- form.qualid.value (166) does not equal qual.empqualid (558) -->
<option value="558">Gardening</option>
<!-- form.qualid.value (166) does not equal qual.empqualid (166) -->
<option value="166">General Manual Labour</option>
<!-- form.qualid.value (166) does not equal qual.empqualid (571) -->
<option value="571">General Manual Labour (Chinese)</option>
```

The middle row should be a match, as the **qual.empqualid** is the same as the **form.qualid.value** (at least it looks like it to me). The variable **form.qualid** is an IntegerField and **qual** is a dictionary that has a key '**empqualid**' that also holds integers. I think that forms emit strings with value()? Is that a possible issue? If so how do I check or change types?

As you can see, django thinks that 166 and 166 are different in some way. Can somebody tell my how this might happen?

Comment: Try using the is operator

Comment: The **is** operator didn't work. I understood it to be a check to see if the two were actually the same object. That isn't the case here: the values are the same, but come from different sources.

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected, it's a type problem. It turns out that **qual.empqualid** was somehow not being interpreted as an integer (it is retrieved from an sql database where it is one) and so the form field **form.qualid** which is an integer was not considered equal.

The fix was to add **|floatformat:"0"** to the end of **qual.empqualid** so they are both being interpreted as integers. The select list now works as expected.

This is odd, because in the same template, I have another select field produced the same way which already works as expected with no floatformat filter. It also compares a database sourced field with a form IntegerField, but it works there.

Bit of a mystery.